# Escaping meta-characters when searching for them in a string?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I was wondering, when trying to do a search for the `.` ,  i tried this:

`'\.'`   , using a back slash to escape the meta-character

however when I tried to see if it would find it on this string:

`My Silly Cat ate my hamster.` Oh well too bad.

my code simply returns False!

however when I tried this:

`'\\.'`  , the code searched the string and returned TRUE!

how and why does it return true when I double backslash the `.` ?

OK here is the code folks, ive omitted the actual html form as its not required but heres the php code snippet im using..

```
<?php   
//  This script takes a submitted string and checks it against a submitted pattern. ( PHP and MySQL for Dynamic Web Sites 4th Edition - Larry Ullman )



//  Check for form submission
if  ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')  {

    //  Make sure neither input was empty upon form submission
    if  (!empty($_POST['pattern']) && !empty($_POST['subject']))    {

    //  Trim the incoming strings
    $pattern = stripslashes(trim($_POST['pattern']));
    $subject = stripslashes(trim($_POST['subject']));

    $counter = 0;
    echo "<p>The result of checking <br /><b>$pattern<b><br />against <br />$subject
        <br />is ";

        if  (preg_match ($pattern, $subject) ) {

            echo 'TRUE!</p>';

        }   else    {

            echo 'FALSE!</p>';

        }

    }   else    {

        echo '<p class="error">One or more fields were not entered - please go back and try again</p>';

    }   //  End of if (!empty($_POST['pattern'] IF

}   //  End of main submit conditional

?>
```

Comment: oddly enough my question itself has removed the backslash heh

Comment: i tried \. first time round but it didnt pick up the '.'.

Comment: second time round i tried \\.  and then and only then did it pick it up.

Comment: Where are you using this? Please add your code

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the actual code you are running. There could be muiltiple reasons for the behaviour you are seeing but without seeing your code there's no way of telling the exact reason.

Comment: how do i paste the code on here ? thats the biggest mind fiddle of the century.

Comment: its almost as if i need to read a 50 page manual on just managing to get my code to appear on your website sir/madam.

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot. Your code was in the question and displaying fine after my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is likely a combination of your code and the way single qouted strings work in php

In php if you make a single quouted string only 2 escape sequences are recognized `\\` and `\'` every other sequence with a backslash will simply be that sequence. (More about that [here](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)) 
So by searching for `\.` you were literally searching for \. (i.E. `My Silly Cat ate my hamster\.` would've been a match)

This is quite simple to fix. Just replace `'\.'` with `'.'` or `"\."`

Comment: there is a counter = 0 line 
which is redundant and was not required in that code.

im omitting it now.

Comment: thats right Nick, '\\.' worked for me in that code.

Comment: @Nick absolutely. I actually have no idea how that happend since from my understanding '\.' and '\\.' should be the exact same. The only thing I can think of is that there was a custom search and replace function